# Are these relationships at ERwin diagram correct?

Tags: database, diagram, erwin

I have to create database application called "Club of alpinists". I have 5 entities: Alpinist, who can be a part of a Team which go to a peak, or Ascend alone. Also there is a Peak, which may have a lot of Routes. 6th entity (Membership) is intermediate. I created relationships between these entities. Could you tell me, are this relationships correct, or there are some mistakes?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zURyb.png)

Comment: _Could you tell me, are this relationships correct_ No I couldn't because the given information is almost zero. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: what is the objective of the use case ?